# reversal of a list of strings using a recursive function

Tags: python, recursion, python-3.x

I am trying to reverse a list using a recursive function. Unfortunatley I am fairly new to recursion. Is this possible? That is my code thus far

```
def stringRev (word):
    worLen = len(word)
    if worLen == 1:
        return word
    return (word[-1]) + stringRev(word[:-1])

listWord = ["hey", "there", "jim"]
print(stringRev(listWord))
```

Comment: Your function works.  It's the input to the function which is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that `(word[-1])` is a string, not a list.  So you are trying to add/concatenate a string and a list.  I changed that expression to `[word[-1]]` to create a list.

```
>>> def stringRev (word):
...     worLen = len(word)
...     if worLen == 1:
...         return word
...     return [word[-1]] + stringRev(word[:-1])
... 
>>> listWord = ["hey", "there", "jim"]
>>> print(stringRev(listWord))
['jim', 'there', 'hey']
>>>
```

PS. It would be helpful if you included the error you received when running your code: `TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly`

Answer (score 3):

To reverse the order of the elements of the list, change:

```
return (word[-1]) + stringRev(word[:-1])
```

to

```
return [word[-1]] + stringRev(word[:-1])
```

(note the square brackets).

The problem is that you are trying to concatenate a string (`word[-1]`) with a list (`word[:-1]`).

The problem is that your function is expecting a single word, yet you're calling it with *a list* of words.

If you call it as follows, you'll see that it works just fine:

```
for word in ["hey", "there", "jim"]:
    print(stringRev(word))
```

Or, if you wish to store the reversed strings in a list:

```
l = [stringRev(w) for w in ["hey", "there", "jim"]]
```

The one corner case where your function would fail is the empty string. I don't know whether that's a valid input, so it could be a non-issue (but trivial to fix nonetheless).

Comment: Im trying to reverse the order of the elements

Answer (score 1):

If you want it done in Python:

```
reversed(listWord)
```

assuming word is a list or a tuple

http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed

And to get a list:

```
list(reversed(listWord))
```

should work

But if you want an algorithm, I guess reversed is not your friend !

Comment: Note that `reversed` doesn't return a string.  It gives you an iterable object.  For that reason, you'll often see `s[::-1]` to reverse a sequence as well.